# inserting cells at the top of the table with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

my app is using core data and i'm using NSFetchedResultsController in order to populate my table. however, when i insert a new cell it get inserted in the table in an alphabetical order fashion (either ascending or descending - according to the sortDescriptor). i want it to be inserted at the top only. i tried commenting out the sortDescriptor but the app crashes since NSFetchedResultsController requires one. any idea how can i fix that? and i got a question probably not that related. now my app has core data and later i want to add icloud support. so do i have to follow the NSFetchedResultsController approach in my code so that my app will be icloud ready later? or i can follow any approach ? i tried other approaches and the primary problem i posted was fixed as it was more flexible.

Comment: you can add a `createdDate` attribute or something similar to your model (if you don't have one already) and use it to order the `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: *face palm* why i didn't think of that! Thanks man! if you want post it down and i'll check it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `createdDate` attribute, or something similar to your model (if you don't already have one). After that you can use this attribute in the `sortDescriptor` to order the `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: I was in a similar boat, I wanted to keep my list in alphabetical order but I also wanted to show the user that a new row had been added, otherwise it could look like nothing had happened. So I use             `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];`